# Problem with chance calculation excercise School

Tags: c#

For a school excercise I need to make an application with a feature that gives you a 50% chance to do double attack damage but for some reason my code doesn't activate. So I'm thinking that something is wrong with my chance calculation. There is a test that does 100 attacks and looks if the damage gets doubled at least once. There SuperModeLikeliness is a float variable with as value 0.5f

```
public void Attack(IHero opponent)
    {
        if (Health > 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            double randomNumber = rnd.NextDouble();
            if (randomNumber <= SuperModeLikeliness)
            {

                opponent.DefendAgainstAttack(Strength * 2);


            }
            else
            {
                opponent.DefendAgainstAttack(Strength);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("attack");
        }
        
    }
```

edit:
As someone has said, I just needed to make the random variable global so that it doesn't keep recreating the random variable.

Comment: Use a "global" Random instance.

Comment: If you call this function 100times inicialize new Random() only once and use it - do not create new Random() each time you call this function.

Comment: ^^ where by "global" I mean a readonly class field that's set once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest the following changes (see code and comments):

```
private readonly Random rnd = new Random();    
public void Attack(IHero opponent)
{
    if (Health > 0)
    {
        // Random rnd = new Random(); // Make this a class field ^^ see above

        // Why "<" ?
        // "Returns a random floating-point number that is greater than 
        //  or equal to 0.0, and less than 1.0."
        //   - [Random.NextDouble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=net-5.0)
        //
        // So, to get really 50:50 chance, we need to check "< 0.5"
        if (rnd.NextDouble() < SuperModeLikeliness) // SuperModeLikeliness = 0.5
        {
            opponent.DefendAgainstAttack(Strength * 2); // I guess `Strength` is a class field.
        }
        else
        {
            opponent.DefendAgainstAttack(Strength);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(Attack)); // add some syntactic sugar
    }
}
```

Another thing:

> There is a test that does 100 attacks and looks **if the damage gets doubled at least once**.

That's probably not a problem, but you need to take into account that there is a *slight* chance that this test will fail, even though nothing's wrong. Also, it doesn't really test if your "chance" requirement is met (at least approximately).

What you could consider is factoring out a "GiveMeA5050Multiplactor" function and then test if it statistically will give result a or b with *about* 0.5 chance.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use "Global" variables (not a good engineering practice anyway)
You can initiate Random with **"Seed"** which is an *Int32* number, if you change it , the random sequence changes as well.
A standard practice is to use some time dependent variable,
for ex: **DateTime.UtcNow.Second**